# The "X" argument does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, console-application

I have a simple symfony console application with following entry point

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Rkmax\Application;

$app = new Application();
$app->run();
```

my Application class

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    public function __construct($name = 'myapp', $version = '0.1')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $version);

        $this->add(new Command\SingleCommand());
    }
}
```

and my command

```
class SingleCommand extends Command
{
    const KEYWORDS = 'keywords';

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName("single")
            ->setDescription("Sample")
            ->addArgument(self::KEYWORDS, InputArgument::OPTIONAL, "Keywords for the search")
        ;
    }

    public function run(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $keywords = $input->getArgument(self::KEYWORDS);
        // ...
    }
}
```

i cant understand where is the problem always i get the error

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]               
 The "keywords" argument does not exist.
```

Comment: what does getArgument look like?

Comment: I dont understand you question

Comment: `$keywords = $input->getArgument(self::KEYWORDS);` what does the `getArgument()` method look like?

Comment: well when you define a argument with `addArgument(...)` in the configure method. you can retrieve with `$input->getArgument()` using the same name, for avoid typos i'm using const for the argument/options names

Comment: okay and where did you call `addArgument(...)` ???

Comment: in the method SingleCommand::configure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably override the **execute** method not **run**.

```
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $keywords = $input->getArgument(self::KEYWORDS);
    // ...
}
```

**run** initializes **$input** and **output**, then validates the **input** and calls **execute($input, $output)** later.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php#L215-L257

Comment: yeah tomas i come from checking that